# How do I get count from multiple columns in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with three columns: State1, State2, State3. Is there a way to get the counts of each state in one dataframe, using all three columns (preferably with dplyr and without an explicit loop)? I only figured out how to do one column:

```
df %>% group_by(State1) %>% summarise(n=sum(!is.na(State1)))
```

Comment: Is it all grouped by 'State1' or individual groupings.  If it is the latter, then you may need a loop.  Please provide a small reproducible example and expected ooutput

Comment: My attempt above is grouped by State1, but I wouldn't say the solution necessarily has to be grouped like that. The factors are the same across all three columns though (50 states + territories).

Comment: Something like `gather(df) %>% group_by(key, val) %>% summarise(n = sum(!is.na(val)))` ?\

Comment: Yup if you expliclty want the non na sum, you should follow @akruns advice. My approach should just add an extra row that counts the NA entries which may be helpful

Comment: @AjjitNarayanan  I think it is better to mention in your post because the question is confusing based on the code

Comment: good point, done

Comment: Removing NAs was not really the focus of my question; I probably should have left it out of the code. Ajjit's solution works is fine in my case since I can deal with NAs later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. You should `gather` all your columns into one column first, then `group_by` and `summarize`.

```
df %>%
    gather("key", "value", state1, state2, state3) %>% 
    group_by(value) %>%
    summarise(n=n())
```

Note: This also counts the number of NA entries if you have any.